# Tensorflow placeholder instance with dynamic dimension

Tags: tensorflow

I'm working with Tensorflow for classifying MNIST, and I'm trying to implement two function

```
data = model.x # placeholder of data. shape is (None, 782)
label = model.y #placeholder of label. shape is (None,)
logit = model.logit # placeholder of logit. shape is (None, 10)
```

These three are placeholder variables that I'm working inside customized class.

What I want to do is to get the logits corresponding `label` only like 
`want = logit[tf.range(n), label]`

However I cannot get `n` from variable since it is declared as dynamic dimension.
Also when I give n as random value, such as 100, then I got error message

```
TypeError: Only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), tf.newaxis (`None`) and scalar tf.int32/tf.int64 tensors are valid indices, got <tf.Tensor 'range_14:0' shape=(100,) dtype=int32>
```

What should I do now? How can I access and fetch value with `label`?

Comment: Can you please share the complete reproducible code so that we can try to help you. Thanks!